# Error loading kernelspec 'pyspark2.2' : Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pyspark, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda on Windows 10 and everytime I open Jupyter Notebook, I get the below error. Can someone please help in understanding the issue an resolution?

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=7902567fdc4d1d33959bd34f85ce21f842677e1efd65ea20
[I 11:35:11.235 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 11:35:14.680 NotebookApp] Error loading kernelspec 'pyspark2.2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pythonREnv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 258, in get_all_specs
    spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pythonREnv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 201, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
    return self.kernel_spec_class.from_resource_dir(resource_dir)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pythonREnv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 47, in from_resource_dir
    kernel_dict = json.load(f)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pythonREnv\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pythonREnv\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pythonREnv\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

Output of jupyter kernelspec list:  jupyter kernelspec list

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-kernelspec-script.py", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(KernelSpecApp.launch_instance())
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspecapp.py", line 273, in start
return self.subapp.start()
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspecapp.py", line 44, in start
specs = self.kernel_spec_manager.get_all_specs()
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 224, in get_all_specs
} for kname in d}
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 224, in <dictcomp>
} for kname in d}
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 192, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
return self.kernel_spec_class.from_resource_dir(resource_dir)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 40, in from_resource_dir
kernel_dict = json.load(f)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

I had created a new file under (C:\Users\myusername.ipython\kernels\pyspark2.2) the following folder which I had created in order to install Apache Spark that will enable Pixiedust on Jupyter Notebook but that is also not working.

Referred the following link to create the below kernels.json file: https://github.com/pixiedust/pixiedust/wiki/Setup:-Install-and-Configure-pixiedust

```
"display_name": "pySpark (Spark 2.3.1) Python 3", "language": "python", "argv": [ "D:\Anaconda3\", "-m", "ipykernel", "-f", "{connection_file}" ], "env": { "SPARK_HOME": "D:\Pixiedust\bin\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\", "PYTHONPATH": "D:\Pixiedust\bin\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\:D:\Pixiedust\bin\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip", "PYTHONSTARTUP": "D:\Pixiedust\bin\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py", "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--driver-class-path D:\Pixiedust\bin\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\data\mllib\* --master local[10] pyspark-shell", "SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY":"10G", "SPARK_LOCAL_IP":"127.0.0.1" } }
```

Thanks
Ganesh Bhat

Comment: What is the result of this: jupyter kernelspec list? The kernel json should be in 'usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/your_kernel', can you paste the output of the kernel you try to access?

Comment: @Merelda Added the requested output & file content in the original post. Thanks, Ganesh